# Add content of Arraylist Hashmap in an integer array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I need one help. I am using 
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();` to store time and temperature value. Now I need to copy all the temperature value in an integer array `int[] temperature`.

To be specific. I use Arraylist to store the value from json as ,

```
// Decleration as
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  JSONArray data = null;


data = json.getJSONArray("value");
for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
String tem = c.getString("temperature");
String time = c.getString("time");
// Adding value HashMap key => value
   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put("tim", tem);
   map.put("time", time);

   list.add(map);
}
```

Now I need to store the temperature value and time in two different arrays . I want them to be stored in following

Temperature to be stored in `int[] temperature`

Time to be stored in `int[] time`

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: why are you ever storing tem and time as Strings? JSON-decoding them into Strings just to have to parse them back to numeric seems problematic.

Comment: Actually I am using the values to plot a chart on achartengine.

Comment: no no, don't use getString() on your JSONObject, use getInt() in the first place!!

Comment: Since I am sending date like `Nov 12 4:35` in my Json I cannot use int  hence my first question structure is current what I have.

Comment: that makes perfect sense for date! for temperature I'd use getInt() if possible. For the date you will want to use getString() and then appropriate functions to convert to a TimeStamp. But I'd do that inside your JSON parsing loop so you end up with a HashMap <String, Float> or something instead of HashMap<String, String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`/*Fill the recorded temperature*/
    int[] temperature = new int[count];
    for(int j = 0; j<count ;j++){
        int a = Integer.parseInt(list.get(j).get("tim"));
        temperature[j] = a;//Log.v("Tep", "val"+a);
    }`
```

This is what I did and it solved my Problem.
I just loop the list and get the indexed element.